# string match and replace in bigram analysis R

Tags: r, str-replace, matching, gsub, n-gram

I am trying to do a bigram analysis on a dataframe `df` with a column `sentence`, which is basically just rows of sentences, using

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidytext)

bigram <- df %>%
unnest_tokens(bigram, sentence, token = "ngrams", n = 2) %>%
separate(bigram, c("word1", "word2"), sep = " ") %>%
count(word1, word2, sort = TRUE)
```

However, I keep getting 'wi' 'fi' as word1 and word2.

For example:

```
A tibble:
word1   word2   n
wi      fi     300
```

I want to replace all the 'wi fi' to 'wifi' so that the output will be:

```
A tibble:
word1   word2    n
good    wifi    400
```

To do this, I used

```
df$sentence <- gsub("\\<wi fi\\>", "wifi", df$sentence)
```

However, when I run the bigram code above, I keep getting 'wi' 'fi' as separate words.
How should I fix this problem?

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. And where does function `unnest_tokens` come from? Please start the script by loading the necessary package(s) with `library(pkgname)`.

Comment: There is no `'wi fi'` in the posted data! What you have is a dataset with *two different column vectors*. One of them has `'wi'` and the other `'fi'`. You can `paste0` them together but then where does the value `'good'` in column 1 come from?

Comment: @RuiBarradas That is just an example of how I want my dataframe to look like. So my dataset isn't two different column vectors from the start. It's just rows of sentences but when tokenize them into bigrams, they become a dataframe of three columns. So basically, I wanted to take all the 'wi fi' in the dataset and change them to 'wifi'.

Comment: If `s` is your string, `gsub('wi fi', 'wifi', s)`. Tokenize after the substitution.

Comment: @RuiBarradas As written in my question, gsub doesn't seem to be working as I keep getting 'wi fi' not 'wifi'. Thank you anyways!

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit the question with the output of `dput(bigram)` after the pipe, after `bigram <- df %>% etc`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(bigram, 20))`.